# How can I find threats/attacks from a PCAP - Wireshark, Snort

Tags: snort, wireshark

I have a `pcap` file and I am trying to analyze it using `Snort` and `Wireshark`.

When I tried the command, which I had showed below, in `Ubuntu` I was provided with various output such as the date, time, source host, destination host, protocol and there are some others like TTL, TOS, ID, IpLen, DgmLen, Ack, Seq.

```
Snort -r myfile.pcap
```

My question is: What do each of these fields mean, and what threats or attacks can be performed with those fields?

> TTL, TOS, ID, IpLen, DgmLen, Ack, Seq

I'm attaching a part of the `Snort` output of the pcap file.[image: Output]

Do I have to write a `Snort` rule in order to detect attacks? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't analyze technical data for attacks if you lack the most basic knowledge of the technology. If you don't know what a sequence number is in TCP, you need to build a foundation. We can't help you.

Comment: Reports that say that something hasn't happened are always interesting to me, because as we know, there are known knowns; there are things we know we know. We also know there are known unknowns; that is to say we know there are some things we do not know. But there are also unknown unknowns -- the ones we don't know we don't know.  -Donald Rumsfeld (former United States Secretary of Defense)